# Responsively select compact or normal sized google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

As per the title looking for help to be able to responsively have Google recaptcha change from the data-size="compact" to data-size="normal" at 768px. Is it possible without javascript?

Captcha HTML:

```
<div class="captcha_container">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le8iBkTAAAAzeCvzZRO3FePZO" data-size="compact">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.captcha_container{padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px; text-align: center;}

.g-recaptcha{ display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the `data-size` without using javascript, however if you'd like, you can change the scale to conform to new screen widths.

example:

```
.g-recaptcha {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.77);
    transform:scale(0.77);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Someone has asked this previously, there were some interesting answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521983/6049581

Comment: Thanks Frits, I'm aware of the scaling option but trying to find a solution with this approach. Its a new feature and currently there is no info online regarding this particular challenge.

Comment: I get you :) Is there a particular reason as to why you are avoiding javascript?

Comment: Just seeing if there was any css trickery. Trying to keep load times down but I have a few functions already. Can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: To be completely honest, my suggestion would be to stick with the CSS. It seems that Google prevents accessing it's dom elements with javascript (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28619922/6049581)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but the jQuery that I would have tried would have been `$('.g-recaptcha').attr('data-size', 'normal');` - I doubt however that this would work, due to Google using the data-size as a parameter before inserting the recaptcha iframe.