# how to fit recaptcha inside a div

Tags: css, recaptcha

I want to put recaptcha inside my div fit. As you know google return the recaptcah as an iframe and can't manipulate it.

```
<style>
.parent{overflow:hidden}
</style>
<div class="parent">
<!-- google recaptcha-->
</div>
```

the problem is google response's width is more than parent's width and the rest of the google response isn't shown.
How can I put the google response inside parent div fit?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691411/change-new-google-recaptcha-width/29521983#29521983

Comment: @colecmc. doesn't work. iframe retrieve from google is wider than parent div. how can I fit google's iframe into parent div

Comment: Google only provide those size options. If neither works, and the scale trick does not work, you will have to find a new technique.

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
.parent iframe {width:100%;}
```

You can't manipulate whatever is inside an `iframe`  but you can set the measures of the `iframe` itself