# How to make google recaptcha responsive with width 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

I need to make google recaptcha responsive not with transform scale only with width 100% and other but not transform scale. I am Searching many other sites but many of them only use transform scale.

here is a image.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS? Without that it's very hard to help you.

Comment: No because i am using API but I'm overwrite this CSS. thanks

Comment: Then I think this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691411/change-new-google-recaptcha-width?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with Google Recaptcha is, that it is loading in an IFrame, so styles do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxx" style="transform:scale(0.88);-webkit-transform:scale(0.88);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxx" data-size="compact"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing your code I'm not 100% sure but try like this:

css

```
#patherdivofgooglecaptcha * {width: 100%}
```

If it works but some elements become too big just limit the CSS where you need it, or if it is an iframe try to give 100% directly on the container and not to the children.